# Click event is not working in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, d3.js

I am using **D3.js** and as well as **backbone.js** also. I want to make a ***click event*** for every path. I have given onclick event as below, but it is not triggering the particular function.

```
  createpath: function(nodes) {
             paths=svg.selectAll("path")
                      .data(nodes)
                      .enter()
                      .append("path")
                      .attr("d",arc)
                      .attr("id",ids)
                      .on("click",  function(d){ return createConcepts(this)})
                      .style("fill","none")
                      .style("opacity", 1)
                      .style("stroke","#c8c8c8");                      
                      this.createText(nodes);

                    }


 function createConcepts(d){    
                   alert("F uuuuuuuuuuu");     
                     }
```

Is it conflicting since i am using both backbone.js and D3.js ??

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rajagopal/jMN7j/1/)

Comment: can you please make a fiddle..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the click event on the paths.  So clicking on the lines will trigger the click event.  But you have fill set to none so clicking the areas between paths will not work.

If you fill the paths with color such as:

```
.style("fill","white")
```

You can also click the areas inside the paths to trigger the click event.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jMN7j/6/

Hope this helps.